# Small soldiers game based on the film

Tags: game-identification

The game is based on the film ‘Small Soldiers’ and the main theme of the game is that you spawn toy characters out of toy boxes to fight against the toy soldiers, I played this game in the late 90’s/early 2000’s, it was also on PC.  Does anyone know this game?

[image: This is the game]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is **Small Soldiers: Squad Commander**, published in 1998 for PC.

[wikia on the subject](http://smallsoldiers.wikia.com/wiki/Small_Soldiers:_Squad_Commander)

Comment: Than you, i loved this game when i was younger.